# How to load openssl.so dynamic library in PHP 5.2.1

Tags: php, dynamic, load, openssl

I recently installed MAMP version 1.6 on my MAC OS 10.5.7. Now I am running a script to connect to a site using ssl.

After some research, I added the following line to my php.ini(under the extensions part)

extension=openssl.so

However When I reestart my Apache server I get this Warning:

[15-Jul-2009 16:30:39] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20050922/openssl.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0

I checked and in fact there is no openssl.so in that folder, am I missing something?. Do I need to recompile php for it to show?. How can i accomplish that?.
Any help will be greatly aprecciated.

Thank you.

-Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [dl](http://php.net/dl) function to dynamically load the openSSL extension:

```
dl('openssl');
```

It is highly likely that MAMP does not have openSSL support enabled, in which case you might want to consider using [macports](http://macports.org) to install your LAMP stack. You can find out if MAMP has openSSL support by adding this to a PHP file:

```
phpinfo();
exit();
```

And look for a configuration line that starts `--with-openssl`.

Answer (score 2):

Note: dl() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and will be removed in 6.0.0.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Comment: Is there any equivalent planned to replace it ?

Comment: @Flawyte: [php.ini extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension)